# Unknown error while generating AET

Tags: windows-phone-8, command-prompt, pfx

I have created my own Test Certificate and **pfx** file. I have refer this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699202.aspx. So now I have pfx file. I am trying to generate **Enrollment Application Token (EAT)** by using **AETGenerator.exe**. When I run this command `AETGenerator.exe PFXFilepath PFXFilePassword` it gives me an error in command prompt

**Unknown error while generating AET**

**startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.**

**Parameter name: startIndex**

what this error means ?

Comment: iam also having same issue, does any one know solution?

Answer (score 0):

I got answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516218/deploy-self-signed-xap-to-windows-phone-8)
It says,

It was indeed as it seemed. You can sign you code with any self signed pfx generated after the latest documentation on the pfx tool.

It is not possible to deploy an App without a company account. This involves paying the $299 and going through the certification process by Symantec.