# Deploy self signed XAP to windows phone 8

Tags: windows, deployment, windows-phone-8, certificate, code-signing

we developed an app for WP8 and wanted to distribute it internally via a download URL to the XAP file. Steps we have taken so far:

1. Use Makecert.exe to generate a self signed XXX.cer with a XXX.pvk (with no password)
2. Used Pvk2Pfx.exe to create a pfx file which includes the private key (with a password)
3. Used XapSignTool.exe to sign our XXX_Release.xap

We also deployed the XXX.cer to the phone device but we still get the error "Can't install company app".

After that we tried to generate a Application enrollment token (AET) with AetGenerator.exe (not 100% sure if we do need this) from out XXX.pfx which exits with an error:

> Unknown error while generating AET startIndex cannot be larger than
>   length of string. Parameter name: startIndex

Any ideas what we are doing wrong or suggestions what would be the way to distribute an app like that? Is it only possible if we have obtained a certificate from Symantec?

Thanks!

PS: I just browsed throught the MS Documentation and for the PFX parameter of the AETGenerator it states:

> Required. The name of the PFX file generated from the enterprise mobile code-signing certificate provided by Symantec.

So most probably it seems that a Symantec $299/year certificate is required. Would this be the correct assumption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was indeed as it seemed. You can sign you code with any self signed pfx generated after the **latest** documentation on the pfx tool.

It is not possible to deploy an App without a company account. This involves paying the $299 and going through the certification process by Symantec.